# C++ pqxx postgresql discrete connection classes, scoping class pointer

Tags: c++, postgresql, smart-pointers, scoping, libpqxx

I have a class, DBProc, which makes a connection to PostgreSQL, and allows user to submit queries/retrieve results.

Functionally, everything works.

The DBProc::connect() function takes an optional argument for connection type. The 3 variants are: direct, lazy, asynchronous.

I have code that instantiates the correct connection class according to user's choice. I initialize 3 unique_ptr<> beforehand, one for each possible connection class, then use an switch statement to choose the selected class type.

This all works fine...but

**My preference would be to have ONE class var that holds a reference to
the connection class**

(all the classes have the exact same functionality), but I see no easy way to do this.
 'auto& currentConnection = lazyConnection' works fine in the switch statement, but of course goes out of scope after the code block.

If there was a way to create a var within a block and allow it to be seen outside the block, without 1st declaring it, that would work, but I don't believe that's possible in c++.

I can't declare it first because all these classes require initialization upon declaration. 
So...c++atch 22 ;-)

So, every time I need to use the connection, I need a switch statement to select the right pointer.

I've looked at templates, unions, extern, and don't see a way to do it with any of these.

If anyone knows if there is a way to do this, please describe.

Here's a code snippet of class func:

```
bool DBProc::connect(ConnectionType type) {

...

unique_ptr<pqxx::connection> connect;
unique_ptr<pqxx::lazyconnection> lzy_connect;
unique_ptr<pqxx::asyncconnection> async_connect;

try
{
    switch (type) {
        case ConnectionType::direct : {
            connect =  make_unique<pqxx::connection>(connOpts);
            break;
        }
        case ConnectionType::lazy : {
            lzy_connect =  make_unique<pqxx::lazyconnection>(connOpts);
            break;
        }
        case ConnectionType::async : {
            async_connect =  make_unique<pqxx::asyncconnection>(connOpts);
            break;
        }
} catch
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why not have a `std::unique_ptr` to [`pqxx::connection_base`](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/4.0/html/Reference/a00023.html) which is the common base class for all connection types?

Comment: Thx! Thought I had tried that, and thought it wouldn't work since pqxx::connection_base is an abstract class...but, hey, it works 8-)

Comment: Working answer from @Some programmer dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working answer provided in comment by 'some programmer dude'

> > Why not have a std::unique_ptr to pqxx::connection_base which is the common base class for all connection types? – Some programmer dude

Simplified code:

```
unique_ptr<pqxx::connection_base> base_connect;

try
{
    switch (type) {
        case ConnectionType::direct : {
            base_connect = make_unique<pqxx::connection>(connOpts);
            break;
        }
        case ConnectionType::lazy : {
            base_connect = make_unique<pqxx::lazyconnection>(connOpts);
            break;
        }
        case ConnectionType::async : {
            base_connect =  make_unique<pqxx::asyncconnection>(connOpts);
            break;
        }
        default:
            error += "No valid connection type supplied (direct | lazy | async)";
            return false;
            break;
    }
```